# gcc expect expression when I try to declare pointer and get it by malloc

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, malloc

./drzwoposzukiwanbinarnych.c:84:24: error: expected expression before â)â token

```
char getNewSlowo(){
    slowa *wyraz = (wyraz*) malloc(sizeof(slowa)); //LINE WITH ERROR
    scanf("%s",wyraz->slowo);
    return wyraz->slowo;
}
```

What I am trying to do?

So, I have a struct:

```
typedef struct node{
char *word;
unsigned int arity;
struct node *left,*right,*parent;
}baza;
```

I want to make that pointer word is pointing to - char slowo[30] defined below.

```
typedef struct word{
    char slowo[30];
}slowa;
```

And the point that I am stuck on is the error on the top of this question.
I am extremely tired of coding and my mind is completely overheated right now so my question may be not well formed for what I am sorry if that's the case.

But why I am trying to do this?
I had a problem with assigning a word defined globally to the pointer and I noticed that when I read a new word into that global defined word the word in the struct (pointer) changed also.

Comment: `â)â token` implies you have some non-asci characters in your file.  Check using command-line tool od?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the cast `(wyraz*)` and all will be fine. if you insist on keeping it (although it is unneeded and often considered detrimental), it should be `(slowa *)` instead.

Comment: It was so easy I am now embarrassed... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
slowa *wyraz = (wyraz*) malloc(sizeof(slowa));
```

has mis-matched pointers. It's better to write this like so:

```
slowa *my_slowa = malloc(sizeof *my_slowa);
```

This [removes the pointless cast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169), and uses the `sizeof` operator to ensure the number of bytes allocated matches the type of the pointer.

Code like this is a pretty good argument for never having this cast, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

There's a reason typecasting is called **type** casting and not **variable-name** casting. What you're trying to do is using the name of the just declared variable as a type name, of course that makes no sense. If you're intending to cast away the return value of `malloc()`, you should use a type, and not a variable name:

```
slowa *wyraz = (slowa *)malloc(sizeof(slowa));
```

However, in C, [**you should not cast the return value of malloc.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) Furthermore, it would be less error prone if you used `sizeof(*ThePointer)` versus `sizeof(TheType)` just in case the type ever changes. All in all, write this:

```
slowa *wyraz = malloc(sizeof(*wyraz));
```